# How to check if an image/image link is present in text in android

Tags: android, html, json, image

I am creating an android application. I am getting the response from server in json format. I ma parsing the json response. When I get the content it may contain image or video link. How can I check whether image or video link is present in the content and download the corresponding image or video and display it in my application. I am aware f downloading images and displaying them, but I am not aware of how to check for the link.
My response is in the following format:

```
<p class='para-inside-post'> cool panda <a class='handler_name' href='/@12'>@12</a> </p><img class=\"post-img-tag\" postcreatorid=\"56332edfad441746cbd15000\" src=\"https://image.jpg\" height=\"430px\" width=\"430px\">"
```

I am parsing the text as shown below:

```
postContentSplit = Html.fromHtml(content).toString();
```

Similarly, how can I do the same for images and videos?
All suggestions are welcome. Please help me come out of this issue.

Comment: you can check that is your **content** i.e. data contains any `.jpg/.JPG` or `.png/.PNG` or `.jpeg` extensions for images...

Comment: @MikeM. Can you please show me a sample code piece for that?

Comment: @MikeM. Ok Sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Patterns in order to check url validity

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(potentialUrl).matches()
```

It will return True if URL is valid and false if URL is invalid.